# how to change the up axis in OrbitControl

Tags: three.js

I'm doing mechanical CAD where the "up" is the Z axis (positive towards the sky), but orbitcontrol assumes that Y is the sky. I'm not really willing to change the global axes labeling in my code because it would be a nightmare in the development to jump between mechanical thinking and three.js thinking.

Is there a smart way to change the rotation axis of the control? Or some kind of very local way to change the axes just for the camera/control sub-system?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The version of `OrbitControls` in the three.js dev branch will accommodate any `camera.up` direction.

If you want the camera to rotate around the z-axis, with the z-axis "up", just do this:

```
camera.up.set( 0, 0, 1 );
```

three.js r.67dev

Comment: the switch to the dev version was a bit of a pain in the butt, but I got it working, thanks.

Comment: Thanks man! I've been looking for this for so long now!

Comment: Docs: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.up. Use in combination with `screenSpacePanning=false` to "fly" forwards/backwards by panning down/up.

Comment: Thanks a million. It was going to drive me crazy.